# Symfony2 cache:clear outputs the content of services.yml file

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In Symfony2, everytime I clear my cache via the console:

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

The console prints out the contents of my services.yml file! If I manually delete the cache via `rm -rf app/cache/*` (which I have to do since my console user doesn't have access to the apache user www-data, for some reason, despite being in the same group because the files are created as 640 instead of 660), then the public website also prints it out the FIRST time the page is loaded and the cache is generated.

NOTE: this prints out even if services.yml is NOT loaded in the app/config/config.yml (just by existing, somehow it's being referenced)

We import the services.yml file:

```
# /app/config/config.yml
imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }
- { resource: "@AcmeBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }
```

Then set global services in the services.yml file:

```
# /src/Acme/Bundle/Resources/config/services.yml
# TODO: ALERT! this prints out whenever I clear the cache...
services:
    #This is a service so that we can access the view object anywhere
    acme.view:
        class: Acme\Bundle\Controller\ViewController
        arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ]
```

### Question: Any ideas why this file is printing out every time I clear the cache?

Comment: Well, my first guess is that you put someday this in the code and forgot about it :) Have you tried remove vendors and install once again?

Comment: Good guess, but no. This is only in the services.yml file. It ONLY appears the first time after cache is cleared. And if I change text in the services.yml file, that is what prints out. It is definitely this file.

Comment: I also know that the services are loading, I access one of them globally. So the services.yml file is configured correctly...

Comment: I meant that the code possibly you've put is reading this file and prints it out. And it could be placed in the class which loads services configuration (because after first use it's cached and not used anymore until you clear cache). Did you try to remove vendors and install them again?

Comment: Check out this file if you didn't print out content of services.yml in there: ./vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php

Comment: For the record, I've never edited anything in the /vendor/ folder. But per your suggestion, I deleted vendor folder and ran `php composer.phar install` to reinstall all vendors successfully. The problem was not fixed ;(

Comment: Well it's strange indeed. The best way you will find the reason is use debuger (XDebug) and go through the code step by step. This way you'll be able to find it really fast.

Comment: This the only suggestion I have (although I still think the most likely is my idea from the first comments - maybe somewhere in your listeners?). Please share solution if find it, I'm very curious

Comment: I don't know Symfony well enough yet to have edited any core code, or created listeners. I will look into XDebug. Thanks for your help. If I figure it out I'll post an answer.

Comment: I found the problem and added it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by changing the `/Acme/Bundle/Resources/config/services.yml` services parameters from PHP to YAML format (I created as PHP originally in my testing).

The reference to the service parameters file is hard coded in the  `/Acme/Bundle/DependencyInjection/AcmeBundleExtension.php` in two places.

Here is the broken code:

```
class AcmeBundleExtension extends Extension
{
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $loader = new Loader\PhpFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('services.yml');
}
```

}

Since the services.yml was being loaded as a PHP file, it was just printing out text whenever the cache was recreated. Amazingly, all the services still actually loaded somehow...!

So take note, if you change the config file from PHP to YAML (or vice versa) you have to update:

```
$loader->load('services.yml');
```

(which I did)

But also you must update the loader function from `Loader\PhpFileLoader` to  `Loader\YamlFileLoader`:

```
$loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
```

Of course that seems obvious, but if you are new to Symfony, take note that converting formats of your service config file requires more than just changing your file name.